# AuthenticationException: Invalid credentials! When using right credentials with Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

So I'm using Hazelcast to create a Server and a Client. 
Turns out I get the following exception when trying to run the client.

```
WARNING: hz.client_0 [56086-56015-56176] [3.7.8] Exception during initial connection to /192.168.1.112:5706
com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException: Invalid credentials!
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:530)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:513)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
```

The error comes from:

```
ClientConfig hzConfig = getHzConfig();
hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(hzConfig);
```

getHzConfig:

```
private static ClientConfig getHzConfig() {
    String addresses = Optional.ofNullable(System.getProperty("addresses")).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    String addressList[] = addresses.split(";");

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.setGroupConfig(new GroupConfig("56086-56015-56176", "56086-56015-56176")); 

    ClientNetworkConfig networkConfig = clientConfig.getNetworkConfig();

    for (String address : addressList) {
        networkConfig.addAddress(address);
    }

    return clientConfig;
}
```

Here's my [hazelcast.xml](https://pastebin.com/r0cLi7sQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client config uses the password `"56086-56015-56176"`, but your member config contains group password `"56015-56086-56176"`. I.e. the first and the second parts (dash separated) are swapped.

This is the proper client config:

```java
clientConfig.setGroupConfig(new GroupConfig("56015-56086-56176", "56015-56086-56176"));
```

**Update:**
Make sure the Hazelcast member takes the proper configuration file on the server-side. It searches `hazelcast.xml` in the current directory by default. You can provide the path explicitly - either use a programmatic way:

```java
Config config = new XmlConfigBuilder("/path/to/hazelcast.xml").build();
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Or if you use the simple `Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()` you can control it by `hazelcast.config` system property:

```sh
java -Dhazelcast.config=/path/to/hazelcast.xml ...
```

Comment: Thank you, now I've changed them and I still get the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't think the server is taking the new hazelcast.xml, could that be possible?

Comment: I had the file hazelcast.xml wrongly placed thnk you

Answer (score 1):

Your server has group name `56015-56086-56176`.

Your client has group name `56086-56015-56176`.

First two sections of the trio are transposed.

Same for password. Note also the password is deprecated from 3.8 onwards, see [here](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.2/manual/html-single/index.html#cluster-groups-before-hazelcast-382)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting the same exception, any idea why?

Comment: I don't think the server is taking the new hazelcast.xml?